# How to generate next auto increment number in mysql using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying to fetch next auto increment number in mysql using php. I tried this way:

```
<?
$q=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
$next_auto_inc=mysql_num_rows($q)+1;
?>
```

But, this when any row is deleted don't work. I hope you got what I mean. How can I do this using php?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 2):

You can't do that fetching the table data. You have to fetch the table status to get the auto increment number using php. And that, you can do something like this:

```
$q = mysql_query("SHOW TABLE STATUS LIKE 'test'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$next_increment = $row['Auto_increment'];
echo "next increment number: [$next_increment]";
```

Hope this helps :)

[[Source](http://blog.eprakash.info/2011/10/get-next-auto-increment-number-in-mysql.html)]

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have `user_id` column as primary key you can also try this:

```
$q = mysql_query('SELECT MAX(user_id) as user_id from `users`');
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($q);
$next_auto_inc = $row['user_id'] + 1;
```